# Facebook on Android - Share with preview window

Tags: android, facebook, share

I'm developing an application that's supposed to post stuff on Facebook wall. I managed to get the SDK working and to post successfully, no problem.

However, I was wondering whether there was an option of seeing the Facebook share post before actually posting it - you know, like the usual share on Web, where you get this window that allows you to add a comment to the post, with "Post" and "Cancel" buttons. For now all the posting is done behind the scenes with no user interaction other than the initial log-in.

Is there a proper way to do this using the SDK, or do I have to make a specialized UI that displays the post's preview?

Answer (score 1):

`Facebook.dialog` was the answer.

Thank you, Facebook, for the obscure SDK examples and documentation. What would our life be without you? About the same, I guess.